# Azure AdB2C Password Expiration

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I've a tenant with an Azure ADB2C directory. I use only local acounts and when I try to reset the password  through the Azure portal it generates a temp password but at the next login I get "Your password has expired."

Any solutions?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yeah.. This is one of things wrong with the UX in the portal right now.

If you reset the password for a local user such that they would have to set it on next login, they won't be able to login (unless your policy/flow is made to handle that I guess, which they aren't by default).

You can offer a reset password flow for the users so they can reset it themselves.
Otherwise you'd need to set the password without requiring the user to reset it on login.
You could do this through Azure AD PowerShell for example.